# Why can I not save the current room in Socket.IO?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, express, socket.io

I have been fiddling with socket.io for a few days, and came across this problem. After I update the currentRoom variable in my server.js, the socket still refers to the first room set, in this case the default room is "General."

When a socket leaves its old room to join a new room, the messages sent do not send to the new room, as intended, but instead send to the old room, even though the current room is stored in a variable and is used as a means of locating the socket's room.

My server.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const http = require('http');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const socketIo = require('socket.io');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const webpackDevMiddleware = require('webpack-dev-middleware');
const webpackConfig = require('./webpack.config');

const app = express();
const server = http.createServer(app);
const io = socketIo(server);

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.use(webpackDevMiddleware(webpack(webpackConfig)));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

io.on('connection', socket => {
  var rooms = ['General'];
  var currentRoom;
  const defaultRoom = 'General';

  socket.join('General');
  currentRoom = "General";

  //socket.emit('setup', { rooms:rooms, currentRoom: currentRoom });

  socket.on('new room', room => {
    socket.leave(currentRoom)
    currentRoom = room;
    socket.join(currentRoom);
    socket.emit('new room', room);
    console.log("New room has been created called: " + currentRoom);
  })

  socket.on('message', body => {
    console.log("Sending message to current room: " + currentRoom);
    socket.to(currentRoom).emit('message', {
      body,
      from: socket.id.slice(8)
    })
  })
})

server.listen(3000);
```

On the front end I have this react component **info.js**:

```
import React from 'react';
import io from 'socket.io-client';

import Room from './Room';
import RoomList from './RoomList';
import User from './User';
import UserList from './UserList';

export default class Info extends React.Component {
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {
      users: [],
      rooms: [],
      currentRoom: ''
    }
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    this.socket = io('/');
    //set defaults for room list
    this.socket.on('setup', data => {
      this.setState({ rooms: [...this.state.rooms, data.rooms] });
      this.setState({ currentRoom: data.currentRoom });
    })
    this.socket.on('new room', room => {
      this.setState({ currentRoom: room });
    })
  }

  userSubmit = event => {
    const username = event.target.value
    if(event.keyCode === 13  && username){
      this.setState({ users: [...this.state.users, username] });
      this.socket.emit('new user', username)
      event.target.value = '';
    }
  }

  roomSubmit = event => {
    const room = event.target.value
    if(event.keyCode === 13  && room){
      this.setState({ rooms: [...this.state.rooms, room] });
      this.socket.emit('new room', room)
      event.target.value = '';
    }
  }

  render(){
    const rooms = this.state.rooms.map((room, index) => {
      return <li key={index}>{room}</li>
    })

    const users = this.state.users.map((user, index) => {
      return <li key={index}>{user}</li>
    })
    return(
      <div class="chat-info">
        <RoomList rooms={rooms}/>
        <Room roomSubmit={this.roomSubmit}/>

        <UserList users={users}/>
        <User userSubmit={this.userSubmit}/>
        <p>Current Room: {this.state.currentRoom}</p>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

When I change rooms via the 'new room' event, the current room **does** get updated, and the socket appears to join the new room; however when the socket then uses the 'message' event to send a message to the current room, the message of the socket gets sent to the default room 'General'. Why does this happen? I'm new to Socket.IO so there is probably something obvious I am not seeing. Any help would be appreciated. Cheers!

Edit: From the console.log's in server js from the new room and message events, I get in my terminal:

```
New room has been created called: new //new refers to the value of currentRoom
Sending message to current room: General //General refers to the value of currentRoom
```

These terminal messages come after I have created a new room on the client and have tried to then send a message after creating and joining that new room. As you can see, I have created and joined a new room simply called "new", but when I try to send a message now to the currentRoom, the message is instead sent to the "General" room.

Edit#2: Here are the logs from a debug I ran on my server.js file.

```
      express:router dispatching GET /bundle.js +56ms
      express:router query  : /bundle.js +0ms
      express:router expressInit  : /bundle.js +1ms
      express:router serveStatic  : /bundle.js +0ms
      send stat "/Users/alexwerner/Desktop/development/Web Development/rooms.io/public/bundle.js" +0ms
      express:router webpackDevMiddleware  : /bundle.js +1ms
      engine intercepting request for path "/socket.io/" +149ms
      engine handling "GET" http request "/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=LQMogAC" +0ms
      engine handshaking client "wlJpbWQIxMnTHrEYAAAA" +2ms
      engine:socket sending packet "open" ({"sid":"wlJpbWQIxMnTHrEYAAAA","upgrades":["websocket"],"pingInterval":25000,"pingTimeout":60000})
+1ms
      engine:polling setting request +1ms
      engine:socket flushing buffer to transport +0ms
      engine:polling writing "      �0{"sid":"wlJpbWQIxMnTHrEYAAAA","upgrades":["websocket"],"pingInterval":25000,"pingTimeout":60000}"
+3ms
      engine:socket executing batch send callback +1ms
      socket.io:server incoming connection with id wlJpbWQIxMnTHrEYAAAA +0ms
      socket.io:client connecting to namespace / +1ms
      socket.io:namespace adding socket to nsp / +0ms
      socket.io:socket socket connected - writing packet +1ms
      socket.io:socket joining room /#wlJpbWQIxMnTHrEYAAAA +0ms
      socket.io:client writing packet {"type":0,"nsp":"/"} +0ms
      socket.io-parser encoding packet {"type":0,"nsp":"/"} +1ms
      socket.io-parser encoded {"type":0,"nsp":"/"} as 0 +0ms
      engine:socket sending packet "message" (0) +0ms
      socket.io:socket joining room General +1ms
      socket.io:socket joined room /#wlJpbWQIxMnTHrEYAAAA +0ms
      socket.io:socket joined room General +0ms
      engine intercepting request for path "/socket.io/" +1ms
      engine handling "GET" http request "/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=LQMogAJ" +0ms
      engine handshaking client "Mh_obCHm_rGKbN2NAAAB" +1ms
      engine:socket sending packet "open" ({"sid":"Mh_obCHm_rGKbN2NAAAB","upgrades":["websocket"],"pingInterval":25000,"pingTimeout":60000})
+0ms
      engine:polling setting request +0ms
      engine:socket flushing buffer to transport +0ms
      engine:polling writing "      �0{"sid":"Mh_obCHm_rGKbN2NAAAB","upgrades":["websocket"],"pingInterval":25000,"pingTimeout":60000}"
+1ms
      engine:socket executing batch send callback +0ms
      socket.io:server incoming connection with id Mh_obCHm_rGKbN2NAAAB +0ms
      socket.io:client connecting to namespace / +1ms
      socket.io:namespace adding socket to nsp / +0ms
      socket.io:socket socket connected - writing packet +0ms
      socket.io:socket joining room /#Mh_obCHm_rGKbN2NAAAB +0ms
      socket.io:client writing packet {"type":0,"nsp":"/"} +0ms
      socket.io-parser encoding packet {"type":0,"nsp":"/"} +0ms
      socket.io-parser encoded {"type":0,"nsp":"/"} as 0 +0ms
      engine:socket sending packet "message" (0) +1ms
      socket.io:socket joining room General +0ms
      socket.io:socket joined room /#Mh_obCHm_rGKbN2NAAAB +0ms
      socket.io:socket joined room General +0ms
      engine upgrading existing transport +40ms
      engine:socket might upgrade socket transport from "polling" to "websocket" +1ms
      engine intercepting request for path "/socket.io/" +4ms
      engine handling "GET" http request "/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=LQMogB2&sid=wlJpbWQIxMnTHrEYAAAA"
+0ms
      engine setting new request for existing client +0ms
      engine:polling setting request +0ms
      engine:socket flushing buffer to transport +0ms
      engine:polling writing "�40" +1ms
      engine:socket executing batch send callback +0ms
      engine intercepting request for path "/socket.io/" +0ms
      engine handling "GET" http request "/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=LQMogB4&sid=Mh_obCHm_rGKbN2NAAAB"
+0ms
      engine setting new request for existing client +0ms
      engine:polling setting request +0ms
      engine:socket flushing buffer to transport +0ms
```

Note that there are two sockets being created; however, I have only opened the application on one browser at one time. I am not sure if this is how socket.io works or if this could be my problem.

Event Logs:

```
socket.io-parser decoded 2["new room","New Room"] as {"type":2,"nsp":"/","data":["new room","New Room"]} +0ms
  socket.io:socket got packet {"type":2,"nsp":"/","data":["new room","New Room"]} +0ms
  socket.io:socket emitting event ["new room","New Room"] +0ms
  socket.io:socket leave room General +0ms
  socket.io:socket joining room New Room +0ms
  socket.io:client writing packet {"type":2,"data":["new room","New Room"],"nsp":"/"} +0ms
  socket.io-parser encoding packet {"type":2,"data":["new room","New Room"],"nsp":"/"} +0ms
  socket.io-parser encoded {"type":2,"data":["new room","New Room"],"nsp":"/"} as 2["new room","New Room"] +0ms
  engine:socket sending packet "message" (2["new room","New Room"]) +0ms
  engine:socket flushing buffer to transport +0ms
  engine:ws writing "42["new room","New Room"]" +1ms
New room has been created called: New Room
  socket.io:socket left room General +0ms
  socket.io:socket joined room New Room +0ms
  engine:ws received "42["message","Test Post"]" +11s
  engine:socket packet +1ms
  socket.io-parser decoded 2["message","Test Post"] as {"type":2,"nsp":"/","data":["message","Test Post"]} +0ms
  socket.io:socket got packet {"type":2,"nsp":"/","data":["message","Test Post"]} +0ms
  socket.io:socket emitting event ["message","Test Post"] +0ms
Sending message to current room: General
  socket.io-parser encoding packet {"type":2,"data":["message",{"body":"Test Post","from":"aDw0sZU_XZAAAE"}],"nsp":"/"} +14.8m
  socket.io-parser encoded {"type":2,"data":["message",{"body":"Test Post","from":"aDw0sZU_XZAAAE"}],"nsp":"/"} as 2["message",{"body":"Test Post","from":"aDw0sZU_XZAAAE"}] +0ms
  socket.io:client writing packet ["2[\"message\",{\"body\":\"Test Post\",\"from\":\"aDw0sZU_XZAAAE\"}]"] +0ms
  engine:socket sending packet "message" (2["message",{"body":"Test Post","from":"aDw0sZU_XZAAAE"}]) +0ms
  engine:socket flushing buffer to transport +0ms
  engine:ws writing "42["message",{"body":"Test Post","from":"aDw0sZU_XZAAAE"}]" +0ms
  socket.io:client writing packet ["2[\"message\",{\"body\":\"Test Post\",\"from\":\"aDw0sZU_XZAAAE\"}]"] +1ms
  engine:socket sending packet "message" (2["message",{"body":"Test Post","from":"aDw0sZU_XZAAAE"}]) +0ms
  engine:socket flushing buffer to transport +0ms
  engine:ws writing "42["message",{"body":"Test Post","from":"aDw0sZU_XZAAAE"}]" +0ms
  engine:ws received "2" +4s
  engine:socket packet +0ms
  engine:socket got ping +0ms
  engine:socket sending packet "pong" (undefined) +0ms
  engine:socket flushing buffer to transport +0ms
  engine:ws writing "3" +0ms
  engine:ws received "2" +0ms
  engine:socket packet +1ms
  engine:socket got ping +0ms
  engine:socket sending packet "pong" (undefined) +0ms
  engine:socket flushing buffer to transport +0ms
  engine:ws writing "3" +0ms
  engine:ws received "2" +3s
  engine:socket packet +0ms
  engine:socket got ping +0ms
  engine:socket sending packet "pong" (undefined) +0ms
  engine:socket flushing buffer to transport +0ms
  engine:ws writing "3" +0ms
  engine:ws received "2" +1ms
  engine:socket packet +0ms
  engine:socket got ping +0ms
  engine:socket sending packet "pong" (undefined) +0ms
  engine:socket flushing buffer to transport +0ms
```

Comment: Why do you think it gets sent to the `General` room?  What evidence of that do you have?  Do you realize that a socket can be joined to many rooms at once so when you join it first to `General` and then to a new room, the socket is still in the `General` room.  You didn't `leave` that room so it's still in that room too.

Comment: @jfriend00 -- I updated the code to show the logs I have been getting from my server file, and I also set the socket to leave the current room when a new room is being created. I believe, but could be wrong, the message is being sent to the General room because on the **message** event, i send a log which I believe tells me the name of the currentRoom at the time the message is sent. When the currentRoom changes under the new room event, the message event still uses the default General room that gets set upon the connection of the socket.

Comment: Do you realize that in your code `currentRoom` is unique for every single socket? There isn't just one `currentRoom` on your server, but every single socket has its own `currentRoom` variable? So, if some other socket sends `new room`, that will change the `currentRoom` only for that specific socket. You can logically think of it as a property of the server-side socket object as if it was `socket.currentRoom`. So, when a socket sends `message`, that message will get sent to the `currentRoom` for the sending socket, not the last `currentRoom` that some other socket set.

Comment: Also, you said you updated the code to show the logs you've been getting, but I don't see any logs in your question at all.  It might also help if you show the client code and show exactly what the client code sees.  I still don't know why you think messages are being sent to the wrong room.  You have not yet explained why you think that.  Are there multiple clients involved and some client in the `General` room is getting a message that is only supposed to be for some other room?  If so, please explain in detail.  We can help you, but only if you give us more info.

Comment: By any chance is `roomSubmit()` in the client being called from a submit button in a form?  And, might that submit button be causing your page to reload since by default submit buttons do a form post which reloads the page if there's no actual form to submit thus creating a new, from scratch socket.io connection that will, of course, be in the `General` room again as all new sockets are?  You could see this more clearly if you put a `console.log()` statement in the `io.on('connection', ...)` code so you can see all new connections getting logged.

Comment: @jfriend00 I have updated my post again; I'm sorry for not giving you all the information you need. My problem is exactly as you describe. Say i have two sockets on the server, when the two users join they join the defaultRoom("General") where they can both send messages. I would like it so that when a user creates a new room, they leave the old room and join the new room, where they can only receive messages from other users in that room. Currently, when a user creates and joins a new room, messages sent still go to the 'General' room instead of the new room created.

Comment: @jfriend00 also roomSubmit() strictly uses and input field right now and checks for the enter key to be pressed for submission.

Comment: Are you sure that `<input>` field is not inside a `<form>`?  Well, you should add logging to `io.on('connection', ....)` just in case something else is causing the page to reload and thus a new connection to be established (one that is in the `General` room, not in the room you wanted it in).  This is a common mistake with both Enter and submit buttons so it's worth making absolutely sure this isn't happening to you and it would explain why state keeps getting reset.

Comment: @jfriend00 -- Yes, the input is only wrapped in a div element. I have uploaded the logs from the debugging of my server file as well, if that helps at all.

Comment: I don't see any logging that ever shows joining any room besides `General` and the automatic room of the same name as the `id`.

Comment: @jfriend00 The logging was from the initial opening of the application. When i test my new room event, the logger shows the socket leaving the 'General' room and joining the new room. That is all. And when a message is sent, the logger shows the message event being emitted.

Comment: Why are you holding back the logging for the most relevant part (where you join the new room and then send a message to it)?  I want to see the whole sequence including that.

Comment: @jfriend00 added event logs with message and new room event

Comment: It appears you have two clients in this log situation.  Let's call them clientA and clientB.  From the logs, I can't tell which logging goes with which client.  Let's say that clientA sends the first "new room" message.  Immediately after that, there is a ["message", "Test Post"].  Which client is sending that message?  Is that sent by clientA or by clientB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After realizing there were two sockets upon creation, I realized my problem sat somewhere in that bit of code. Turns out I was not nesting Socket.IO correctly in my react project. I had multiple instances where a component was importing socket.io on the client.

(I had this line in more than one component):

```
import io from 'socket.io-client';
```

Turns out using this import will create multiple sockets if it is used more than once in the project. (Which makes sense, and it's unfortunate it took me so long to catch my mistake).

In case anyone has trouble with multiple sockets being created when using the React framework, the solution is easy to implement. Firstly, remove the socket.io imports on your components, and move the statement to a parent component. In my case this was my layout component.

**Layout.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import io from 'socket.io-client';

import Chat from './Chat/Chat';
import Info from './Info/Info';

const socket = io();

export default class Layout extends React.Component {
  render(){
    return(
      <div class="wrapper">
        <h1>Rooms.io!</h1>
        <Chat socket={socket}/>
        <Info socket={socket}/>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Now that the import statement is in a parent component. You can pass the socket from the parent component to any of the children components. As you can see, I pass the socket to two components Chat and Info.

In those children components, you can treat the socket like you would with any other sort of prop in React. In my example, currently, I set the socket variable to equal the socket prop, **(As seen in my componentDidMount function).**

Chat.js

```
import React from 'react';

import Message from './Message';
import MessageList from './MessageList';

export default class Chat extends React.Component {
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = { messages: [] };
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    const socket = this.props.socket;
    socket.on('message', message => {
      this.setState({ messages: [...this.state.messages, message] });
    })
  }

  handleSubmit = event => {
    const socket = this.props.socket;
    const body = event.target.value
    if(event.keyCode === 13  && body){
      const message = {
        body,
        from: 'Me'
      }
      this.setState({ messages: [...this.state.messages, message] });
      socket.emit('message', body)
      event.target.value = '';
    }
  }

  render(){
    const messages = this.state.messages.map((message, index) => {
      return <li key={index}>{message.from}: {message.body}</li>
    })
    return(
      <div class="chat">
        <MessageList messages={messages}/>
        <Message handleSubmit={this.handleSubmit}/>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Thanks to @jfriend00 for the help; I hope anyone reading this has a nice day and never forgets to properly nest their sockets in React. Cheers!